# How can I limit the results of the below foreach to the first 4 only

Tags: foreach

{foreach from=$aFeed.feed_image item=sFeedImage}

{$sFeedImage}

{/foreach}

Comment: Maybe you can use "for" instruction instead of "foreach" ?

for($i = 0; $i <4 ; $i++)
{//your code
} 

is that a way possible to do it for you ?

Comment: could you please tell me how i could write this thanks in advance

Comment: yes no problem , just pls give me more informations, what's your array ? what you want to display ( which row ) ? php,java,c#, js  .. ?

Comment: Hi, this is from a phpfox template i would like to only display the first 4 images .                                                                                                               The code (part of it) below                                                                     {if is_array($aFeed.feed_image)}
<ul class="activity_feed_multiple_image">                                   {foreach from=$aFeed.feed_image item=sFeedImage}                        <li>{$sFeedImage}</li>{/foreach}</ul>
{else}

Comment: i have post an aswer tell me if that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

To display only 4 first resuls from an array you can do something like this :

```
for($i=0 ; $i<4 ; $i++)
{
   echo $myarray[i]['column name'];
}
```

you can also only try this if you don't need to precise the column name :

```
for($i=0 ; $i<4 ; $i++)
{
   echo $myarray[i];
}
```

Comment: thank you (but I have no clue how to write this) my template is written with brackets {foreach}

Comment: @Takis M i'm not in your code you have to adapt this to your own work bro . If the answer is good for you don't forget to check the answer to put the post as "resolved" for other people please .

Comment: @TakisM not a problem buts it's a good way to do it without any problems just adapt this code . And don't forget check answer when you think it's ok for you